# /sys/class/power_supply/battery VS. BatteyManager

Tags: android, android-service, battery, batterylevel

As far as i understand, there are 2 ways to read battery status:

1) Register a broadcast receiver on `"ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED"` and get the values from the Intent using `BatteryManager` fields.
2) Read values directly from `sysfs` battery files.

My question is which way is better? what are the pros/cons of each method?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what u want from battery. U want to get battery status that how much it remains is this your requirement

Comment: I want to get as much information as possible (voltage/temp./etc...). if there are some limitations for getting the information in a specific method I will be happy to know about it. @BhanuSharma. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- sysfs is more effectivity,
  but lose generality: different device may have different sysfs path about battery info.

  found something here: [http://blog.hissummer.com/2012/11/android-中如何获取电池的电流值/](http://blog.hissummer.com/2012/11/android-%E4%B8%AD%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95%E8%8E%B7%E5%8F%96%E7%94%B5%E6%B1%A0%E7%9A%84%E7%94%B5%E6%B5%81%E5%80%BC/)
- BatteryManager is more general: hiding the hardware difference.